# How do I set default values in forge.prefs?

Tags: trigger.io

I'm using Trigger.io's forge.prefs module to store user options. The [documentation](https://trigger.io/modules/prefs/current/docs/index.html) refers to "default values" for preferences a few times:

> **forge.prefs.set(name, value, success, error)**
>
> The preference value given here will override a default value (if one was given).

However, I can't anything in the docs that actually says how to set this default value.

How do you set a default value for a preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the trigger.io tutorial on [creating a weather app](https://trigger.io/docs/current/getting_started/tutorial/tutorial-4.html) in particular the section **Using remembered locations** as a strategy for setting a default preference value.

Comment: So, there's no way to set a global default or anything like that, you're just doing typical null value safety netting and providing some value to ensure the calling code doesn't get a null. That's just a lazy API declaration. Which isn't your issue, I know. The more I use Forge via Trigger, the more I know I need to just rewrite the app in native code. :(